# Custom Expression Converter never called

Tags: data-exchange-framework

In DEF 4.0 and SC 9.3, using this [Sitecore guide](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/def/40/data-exchange-framework/filter-which-entries-to-synchronize.html) I created a custom Value Expression Converter for a new filter so that I can filter generic Events based on the `DefinitionId`, in this case Print events:

[image: Custom Filter Expression]

[image: Expression Converter]

This custom expression converter was based off a similar converter that ships with DEF:

[image: EventTypeExpressionConverter]

I have confirmed that the library reference in the `Converter Type` field is valid, and when I run the pipeline, I see the base constructor getting called inside of my custom converter (first break point), but I never see any other code being called (second break point). This is obvious because Events are being synced that shouldn't be based on the filters that I have specified.

The high level flow is this:

- Pipeline: Process Single Interaction from xConnect

  - Pipeline Step: Read Page Events from Interaction

    - Source Object Value Accessor: **"Data Access/Value Accessors/Providers/xConnect/Page Events from Interaction"**
    - Filter: **"Filter Expressions/Event Filter Expressions/Print Event Expression"**

      - Condition Operator: **“Equal”**
      - Right Value Accessor: **"DefinitionId on xConnect Event"**
      - Value: **"Page Events/Print"** ({CD52B756-21B4-4028-8BA5-E981B8A96F95})
      - Converter Type: **"Client.Foundation.DataExchange.Providers.xConnect.Expressions.GenericEventDefinitionTypeValueExpressionConverter, Client.Foundation.DataExchange"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been quite a while since I worked on this, but I did get it working. If I recall correctly, the issue was in the code and not in DEF settings items, and the reason it wasn't getting picked up was because a reference to an interface or class needed to be updated. This combination of code worked:

```
public class EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionBuilder : BaseEventDefinitionTypeExpressionBuilder<Guid>
{
    public IValueAccessor RightValueAccessor { get; set; }

    public Guid EventDefinitionType { get; set; }

    protected override Expression<Func<Event, bool>> BuildEventExpression(
      ExpressionContext expressionContext)
    {
        Guid eventDefinitionType = this.GetValue(expressionContext);
        switch (this.ExpressionType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Equal:
                return (Expression<Func<Event, bool>>)(ev => ev.DefinitionId.Equals(eventDefinitionType));
            case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                return (Expression<Func<Event, bool>>)(ev => !ev.DefinitionId.Equals(eventDefinitionType));
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Condition operator is not supported. (Condition operator: {0})", (object)this.ExpressionType));
        }
    }

    protected override Guid GetValue(
      ExpressionContext expressionContext)
    {
        if (this.RightValueAccessor?.ValueReader != null)
        {
            ReadResult readResult = this.RightValueAccessor.ValueReader.Read((object)expressionContext, new DataAccessContext());
            if (readResult.WasValueRead)
            {
                return readResult.ReadValue as Guid? ?? Guid.Empty;
            }
        }
        return this.EventDefinitionType;
    }
}
```

```
public class EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<IEventExpressionBuilder>
{
    public const string FieldNameConditionOperator = "ConditionOperator";
    public const string FieldNameValue = "Value";
    public const string FieldNameRightValueAccessor = "RightValueAccessor";
    protected readonly ExpressionTypeConverter ExpressionTypeConverter;

    public EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : this(repository, new ExpressionTypeConverter())
    {
    }

    public EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionConverter(
        IItemModelRepository repository,
        ExpressionTypeConverter expressionTypeConverter)
        : base(repository)
    {
        this.ExpressionTypeConverter = expressionTypeConverter ?? new ExpressionTypeConverter();
    }

    protected override ConvertResult<IEventExpressionBuilder> ConvertSupportedItem(ItemModel source)
    {
        string conditionOperator = this.GetConditionOperator(source);
        ExpressionType expressionType;

        if (!this.TryGetExpressionType(conditionOperator, out expressionType))
        {
            return this.NegativeResult(source, "Cannot convert string condition operator to expression type. (condition operator: " + conditionOperator + ")");
        }

        Guid eventDefinitionId = this.GetEventDefinitionId(source);
        IValueAccessor rightValueAccessor = this.GetRightValueAccessor(source);

        EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionBuilder expressionBuilder = new EventDefinitionIdValueExpressionBuilder();

        expressionBuilder.EventDefinitionType = eventDefinitionId;
        expressionBuilder.ExpressionType = expressionType;
        expressionBuilder.RightValueAccessor = rightValueAccessor;

        return this.PositiveResult((IEventExpressionBuilder)expressionBuilder);
    }

    protected virtual IValueAccessor GetRightValueAccessor(ItemModel source) => this.ConvertReferenceToModel<IValueAccessor>(source, "RightValueAccessor");

    protected virtual Guid GetEventDefinitionId(ItemModel source)
    {
        return this.GetGuidValue(source, "Value");
    }

    protected virtual string GetConditionOperator(ItemModel source) => this.GetReferenceAsModel(source, "ConditionOperator")["ItemName"].ToString();

    protected bool TryGetExpressionType(string conditionOperator, out ExpressionType expressionType)
    {
        return Enum.TryParse<ExpressionType>(conditionOperator, true, out expressionType);
    }
}
```

```
public class EventDefinitionIdValueReaderConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<IValueReader>
{
    private static EventDefinitionIdValueReader _reader = new EventDefinitionIdValueReader();

    public EventDefinitionIdValueReaderConverter(IItemModelRepository repository): base(repository)
    {
    }

    protected override ConvertResult<IValueReader> ConvertSupportedItem(
      ItemModel source)
    {
        return this.PositiveResult((IValueReader)EventDefinitionIdValueReaderConverter._reader);
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class BaseEventDefinitionTypeExpressionBuilder<TValue> : IEventExpressionBuilder
{
    public ExpressionType ExpressionType { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<Event, bool>> Build(ExpressionContext expressionContext)
    {
        Expression<Func<Event, bool>> expression = this.BuildEventExpression(expressionContext);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Event, bool>>(expression.Body, (IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>)expression.Parameters);
    }

    protected abstract Expression<Func<Event, bool>> BuildEventExpression(ExpressionContext expressionContext);

    protected abstract TValue GetValue(ExpressionContext expressionContext);
}
```

For supplementary material, I have more code examples and explanations on these posts:

- https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/data-exchange-framework-dynamics-connector-overview
- https://sitecore.marcelgruber.ca/posts/storing-full-urls-in-page-view-events

Answer (score 2):

I can't see it from the screenshot, do you specify expression converter item template ID in the `[SupportedIds]` attribute for your custom Expression Converter class?

If not, the constructor of this class will be called, but `BaseItemModelConverter<>` will never reach its method `ConvertSupportedItem()`.
Here is how it works internally:

- when an instance of a converter class is created, its constructor gets a collection of supported template IDs from the attribute `[SupportedIds]`
- then the method `Convert()` of `BaseItemModelConverter<>` is executed and it checks that the passed source item template ID exists in the list of supported IDs

  - if yes, the overridden method `ConvertSupportedItem()` will be called
  - if not, `Convert()` will return a negative result and `ConvertSupportedItem()` will not run

So your custom Expression Converter class definition should look similar to this:

```
[SupportedIds("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}")]
public class FilterExpressionConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<FilterExpressionDescriptor>
{
...
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation but I don't think that it applies in this case -- if we take a look at the `BaseItemModelConverter`, it has a method called `IsSupportedItem`, whereby a check is done for `this.IgnoreValidation || !this.SupportedTemplateIds.Any<Guid>()` meaning that if we set `IgnoreValidation` to `true` (which I have tried), or if the class has no `SupportedIds` specified, the source item is considered to be a supported item. None of the other default expression converters I looked at specified any `SupportedIds`; for example, the `ContactIdentifierTypeValueExpressionConverter`.

Comment: @MarcelGruber that's interesting, I completely overlooked the line `this.IgnoreValidation || !this.SupportedTemplateIds.Any<Guid>()`. But you are right, the lack of `SupportedIds` attribute should not cause this problem and I can't see any other reason why it skips `ConvertSupportedItem()`. Maybe you can try to override the method `IsSupportedItem(ItemModel source)` to check if it even reaches this point?